# How does svyglm() handle Missing Values?

Tags: r, missing-data, survey, weighted

`svyglm()` has an `na.action = na.omit` argument. Does that mean for any of the covariates, if any are missing for a given sample, it will remove the entire sample's observations?

**I want to only include samples that have values for every covariates.** But When dealing with weighted survey data, I cannot remove values before  weighting (Besides those with missing weight values). So i have to do it after.

Does the svyglm() na.action = na.omit argument do that automatically?  So that it only calculates/evaluates off of samples that have values for every co-variate?

Answer (score 0):

As with other R modelling functions, `svyglm` by default drops observations with any missing values.

From a survey statistics point of view, this is done by taking the non-missing subset and the inference is to the non-missing population.